# Why deleted - How can I tie flashlight to car's passenger side mirror?

Tags: discussion

I don't get why https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/22963/18558 was closed AND deleted. If you delete, how can others see bob1's useful answer with six upvotes?  Even if you don't like, can you still please keep them visible?

Deletion makes me sad and teary. I put many effort.

Comment: If you read the comments, it's clear it got closed as spam. Also those with enough rep can see it anyway for a period of time.

Comment: Welp, I didn't see that it had been migrated to Meta before I VTC. My bad!

Comment: @Aravona but my children or family can't see deleted posts.

Comment: Perhaps that's just as well. The idea that you intend to navigate Norway in winter by flashlight fixed to a door mirror is bizarre. If you really need more lighting please install a proper lighting bar. But you stand more chance of being able to see a snowy landscape with *less* lighting.

Answer (score 8):

As per all the comments under that post, it was closed as spam - we are very strict about self-promotion, promotion or astroturfing on Stack Exchange. Your post was made on various sites, and appears to be a thinly veiled advertisement.

If you do think that you have a question in there that could be asked without heavily promoting a product, and you follow general good behaviours (don't cross post etc) then please ask that.

Comment: Hi Rory. thanks for answer. how can make question less spammy? i can remove the flashlight's name. but i dont want remove picture of flashlight with the shoulder strap, because how else can people see how to add flashlight to car?

Comment: If you are just asking how to attach it to your car, that is really not on topic here - You already linked the reddit answer - which tells you everything.